# URL rewrite (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i should create an .htaccess for redirect. I have never done this before. I have made some test, but without success. I don't understand how to do:

This is incoming link:

```
http://foo.com/numeric_id
```

i want to redirect to:

```
https://www.bar.com/numeric_id-.html
```

To be more specific, this is an example:

```
http://foo.com/250
```

i want to redirect with 301 to:

```
https://www.bar.com/250-.html
```

This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule [0-9]+ https://www.bar.com/$1-.html [R=301,L]
```

Apache simple redirect me to https://www.bar.com .

Where i'm wrong? Can you help me, please?

Best Regards,
Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the URI.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ https://www.bar.com/$1-.html [R=301,L]
```

**Clear your browser's cache before testing this**

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

It was only a Google Chrome Cache issue. My code was almost perfect.

Whis is working version:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteRule [0-9]+ https://www.bar.com/$0-.html [R=301,L]

Thank you all anyway!